# how to use python re to extract value of a specific postion with ouput spanning accross multiple lines

Tags: python

running some linux commands gives output like below:

DV1463L6         LTO      2242GB      2242GB         0GB 4110            -             -    mixedpool  Valid LTFS (exported offline)

DV1464L6         LTO      2346GB      2247GB         0GB 4098               -             -    mixedpool  Valid LTFS

DV1465L6         LTO     2849GB      2248GB         0GB 4103               -             -    mixedpool  Valid LTFS

so this 3 line output
i need to extract 3rd column values from all 3 lines(remember its not table)

Comment: please add some code of what you have tried. among this code, itd be helpful if you can share how you are capturing this output

Comment: also, why not just use 'string.split()[2]` if each line is a string?

Comment: Thanks,but if reference string.split()[2] as some variable value1,in case i want to add all three values of 3rd coulumn,how can that be done?

Comment: please add some code so its more clear what you need/how i can help ya

Comment: there is actually a command called ltfsee info tapes,which gives output as i pasted above,i want the values under 3rd column to be added ,how can that be done